# How to sort a slice of string

Tags: sorting, go

I'm trying to sort a slice of string, which look like "hour:minute:second".

```golang
func main() {
    rows := []string{
        "1:2:8",
        "1:2:5",
        "1:2:6",
    }

    sort.SliceStable(rows, func(i, j int) bool {
        var hour_i, min_i, sec_i int
        var hour_j, min_j, sec_j int

        fmt.Sscanf(rows[i], "%d:%d:%d", &hour_i, &min_i, &sec_i)
        fmt.Sscanf(rows[j], "%d:%d:%d", &hour_j, &min_j, &sec_j)

        return hour_i < hour_j && min_i < min_j && sec_i < sec_j
    })

    for _, x := range rows {
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
}
```

But the result is same to the input, not sorted. Why is that?

Comment: You need `||` not `&&`. Your current logic only considers something "less" if it has a smaller minute _and_ smaller hour _and_ smaller second. Obviously not what you intend :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare each item separately

```
sort.SliceStable(rows, func(i, j int) bool {
    var hour_i, min_i, sec_i int
    var hour_j, min_j, sec_j int

    fmt.Sscanf(rows[i], "%d:%d:%d", &hour_i, &min_i, &sec_i)
    fmt.Sscanf(rows[j], "%d:%d:%d", &hour_j, &min_j, &sec_j)

    if hour_i < hour_j {
        return true
    }

    if min_i < min_j {
        return true
    }

    return sec_i < sec_j
})
```

Comment: or as @Flimzy suggested this can be done in a one-liner: `return hour_i < hour_j || min_i < min_j || sec_i < sec_j`

Comment: Some things need to be clear (or readable)

Answer (score -1):

You can sort your slice using simple `sort.Strings()` method from sort package,modifying your code and sorting it with the same logic as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {

    rows := []string{
        "1:2:8",
        "1:2:5",
        "1:2:6",
        "2:0:7",
        "1:0:6",
        "2:0:5",
    }

    sort.Strings(rows)
    for _, val := range rows {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }

}
```

Output :

```
1:0:6
1:2:5
1:2:6
1:2:8
2:0:5
2:0:7
```

Comment: Thanks, but the string may be different format like "01:02:03", which may cause wrong sorting order.